# Visual Studio Publish MSdeploy $(SolutionDir)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, publish, msdeploy

I'm having an annoying issue with MSDeploy and Visual Studio's publish profile.  In my project I have a property group that I setup an item to reference later.

```
<LocalBuildLocation>$(SolutionDir)WebSites\MyWebSite\</LocalBuildLocation>
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio will randomly drop the `$(SolutionDir)` string from this property and my build will fail. I copy it back in manually and everything is good to go.

Can anyone think of why this item keeps removing itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [$(SolutionDir) MSBuild property incorrect when running Sandcastle Help File Builder via CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32435599/4183920) and [getting the value of $(ProjectDir), $(SolutionDir) in a vcproj file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4875789/4183920)

It looks like `$SolutionDir` does (sometimes) work with MSBuild, but only if you're building from the solution file. It is the same thing as `$ProjectDir` for the most part.

But you're not supposed to be able to use them in MSBuild. Even though they work sometimes -- it's not reliable. And as pointed out by the other answer:

> Visual Studio macros like $(SolutionDir) don’t work in MSBuild. You
>   can use project properties instead.

Source: [Code Generation in a Build Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx#Anchor_9)

> $(ProjectDir) The directory of the project (defined as drive + path);
>   includes the trailing backslash '\'.
>
> $(SolutionDir) The directory of the solution (defined as drive +
>   path); includes the trailing backslash '\'.

Note that:

> You can use these macros anywhere in a project's Property Pages dialog
>   box where strings are accepted.

Source: [Macros for Build Commands and Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Marked as answer while the other was first this is more in depth and the second link to "macros for build commands and properties" led me to what i needed!  Interesting that $(SolutionDir) its inconsistent in a property group which is the way i'm using it.  I will see if $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) holds up and the build doesn't remove it.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN: Using project properties in assembly and include directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx#Anchor_9)

> Visual Studio macros like `$(SolutionDir)` don’t work in MSBuild. You
>   can use project properties instead.

Use `$(ProjectDir)` (safer, project level property) or `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` (safest, always exist)